# Rows not appending to dataframe while on loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I was working through a database and creating a dataframe of selected information. The database can be found at [www.cricsheet.org](https://cricsheet.org).
The code for the same is:

```
bat = {'Name' : [], 'Runs' : [], 'Balls' : [], 'StrikeR' : []}
batsman = pd.DataFrame(bat)
batsman.head()
index = ['Name','Runs','Balls','StrikeR']

data = []
count = 0
for i in items[0]["1st innings"]["deliveries"]:
    name = list(i.values())[0]["batsman"]
    run = list(i.values())[0]["runs"]["batsman"]
    if name in list(batsman['Name']):
        batsman.loc[batsman.Name == name].Runs += run
        batsman.loc[batsman.Name == name].Balls += 1
        batsman.loc[batsman.Name == name].StrikeR = batsman.loc[batsman.Name == name].Runs/batsman.loc[batsman.Name == name].Balls
    else:
        data = [name,run,1,run]
        print(b)
        batsman.append(pd.Series(data, index = index), ignore_index=True)
```

To give a context the array `data` is of type:

```
['GC Smith', 0, 1, 0]
['HH Dippenaar', 0, 1, 0]
['HH Dippenaar', 0, 1, 0]
['HH Dippenaar', 2, 1, 2]
['HH Dippenaar', 0, 1, 0]
```

I was hoping to update this data in a pandas dataframe, However the data is not appending to the dataframe. Can anyone tell me why and what is the solution to it?

Edit: I am adding a part of items[0] dataset.

```
{'1st innings': {'team': 'South Africa', 'deliveries': [{0.1: {'batsman': 'GC Smith', 'bowler': 'WPUJC Vaas', 'non_striker': 'HH Dippenaar', 'runs': {'batsman': 0, 'extras': 0, 'total': 0}}}, {0.2: {'batsman': 'GC Smith', 'bowler': 'WPUJC Vaas', 'non_striker': 'HH Dippenaar', 'runs': {'batsman': 0, 'extras': 0, 'total': 0}}}, {0.3: {'batsman': 'GC Smith', 'bowler': 'WPUJC Vaas', 'non_striker': 'HH Dippenaar', 'runs': {'batsman': 0, 'extras': 0, 'total': 0}}}, {0.4: {'batsman': 'GC Smith', 'bowler': 'WPUJC Vaas', 'non_striker': 'HH Dippenaar', 'runs': {'batsman': 0, 'extras': 0, 'total': 0}}}, {0.5: {'batsman': 'GC Smith', 'bowler': 'WPUJC Vaas', 'non_striker': 'HH Dippenaar', 'runs': {'batsman': 0, 'extras': 0, 'total': 0}}}, {0.6: {'batsman': 'GC Smith', 'bowler': 'WPUJC Vaas', 'non_striker': 'HH Dippenaar', 'runs': {'batsman': 0, 'extras': 0, 'total': 0}}}
```

Comment: Could you post some example content of `items`, and/or `items[0]`, enough that it can be copied and pasted into a working example? If it's JSON-like, there's probably a neat way to convert it to a pandas DataFrame and getting the desired output without explicit for-looping and handwritten logic.

Comment: I have added a part of dataset. Please check it out @PeterLeimbigler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hei,

Appending to a dataframe doesn't happen in place. The append function will only return the new dataframe which contains the appended value, and will not modify the original dataframe

So,

```
batsman.append(pd.Series(data, index = index), ignore_index=True)
```

Should be

```
batsman = batsman.append(pd.Series(data, index = index), ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: You are right! would you please tell me if the same thing is happening when I am adding runs as well?

Comment: No, the .loc function does the job in place